# Error: "IndexError: too many indices for array"

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

```
File "convert_to_records.py", line 80, in main
train_images = train_images[:FLAGS.validation_size, :, :, :]
IndexError: too many indices for array
```

I was running the following file:
https://github.com/HamedMP/ImageFlow/blob/master/example_project/convert_to_records.py

and on line 80

```
#validation_images = train_images[:FLAGS.validation_size, :, :, :]
#validation_labels = train_labels[:FLAGS.validation_size]
train_images = train_images[FLAGS.validation_size:, :, :, :]
#train_labels = train_labels[FLAGS.validation_size:]
```

it gives me error "too many indices for array". I commented the other lines out because it was giving me the same error. I was wondering if anyone could give me any insight into this

Before any states the obvious; yes I looked it up. And the solutions offered on google were not useful (I tried them out and they did not work)

Comment: I could be a dimension problem... Are you sure `train_images` is a 4-dimensionnal array ?

Comment: Show the `.shape` and `dtype` of `train_images`

Comment: Search other `tensorflow` tags.  A developer for that code is answering many of those.  But you may need wait till after the holiday.

Comment: okay thanks!
and the train images came with a 4D tag. I can change it if necessary

Comment: I will look up what the developer has to say. Thanks